# Setting up page goals in Analytics when using progressive enhancement to load content using jquery .load

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking, goals

I'm using jQuery `.load` to load content in from other pages into my homepage, so that Google can still see whats going on I've made the `<a>` tags go to the pages but over ride them in the JavaScript so instead of going the that page it just loads in the content from that page to the main page.

Normaly I would just make the page `/contact.html` a goal.

Can I still get it to work as a goal if the content is being loaded in? Can I do something like when the user clicks `<a href="contact.html" id="load-contact">contact</a>` it logs the clicking of the `<a>` tag as a goal, rather than the actaul page being visited?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll want to setup some custom *events* to track as goals... See [here](http://www.blastam.com/blog/index.php/2011/03/how-to-use-events-goals-google-analytics/) for a more in depth explanation.